# Delete lines if two conditions on different lines are satisfied

Tags: string, awk, pattern-matching, conditional-statements, matching

Assume a multi-line text file `file`.

```
$cat file
foo bar baz
foo bar baz qux
foo bar baz quux  # Line to be deleted
foo bar quux
```

I wish to delete all those lines that fullfill both conditions: (a) the line contains the keyword "*quux*", and (b) the line is *immediately* preceeded by a line that contains the keyword "*qux*".

```
$cat file | sought_command
foo bar baz
foo bar baz qux
foo bar quux
```

I am at a loss as to which UNIX tool can be applied for such a double conditionality (probably *awk*, but I am uncertain) and would appreciate suggestions.

**Edit 1**:
Upon being informed that `awk` is the tool to use and upon considering the task further, I am looking specifically for code that can easily be modified such that condition (b) can be inverted (i.e., "(b) the line is NOT immediately preceeded by a line that contains the keyword 'qux' "), if necessary.

Comment: No need to be at a loss: s/old/new => sed, and g/re/p => grep, and anything else (eg. this) => awk. Now - are you looking for string or regexp comparisons and partial or full matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MAY be what you're looking for depending on if you want string or regexp comparisons and partial or full matches.

1) Delete the line if it contains quux and the preceding one contains qux:

```
$ awk '!(/quux/ && p~/qux/); {p=$0}' file
foo bar baz
foo bar baz qux
foo bar quux
```

2) Delete the line if it contains quux and the preceding one does NOT contain qux:

```
awk '!(/quux/ && p!~/qux/); {p=$0}' file
```

which, if you prefer to avoid the double negative, boolean algebra can reduce to:

```
awk '!/quux/ || p~/qux/; {p=$0}' file
```

Any compound condition you like is trivially implemented by just &&-ing and/or ||-ing and/or negating the tests on $0 (implicit in `/.../`) and p.

Comment: I see. So `awk` was the tool after all. Yes, a string comparison is what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Short follow-up: What if I wanted to change condition (b) to "the line is **NOT** immediately preceeded by a line that contains the keyword 'qux'". Would that be simple to implement with your awk one-liner?

Comment: None of the answers here do a string comparison, they all do a regexp comparison with partial matching. The string/regexp difference is important if the text you are matching on (`quux` and `qux`) can contain regexp metacharacters (e.g. `q.*x`). Whether or not partial matches are allowed (e.g. does `qux` match `fooquxbar`?) is probably more relevant. Yes, any change would be trivial: `awk '!(/quux/ && p!~/qux/); {p=$0}' file` which boolean algebra can reduce to `awk '!/quux/ || p~/qux/; {p=$0}' file`.

Comment: Thank your for your patient explanations.

Answer (score 0):

an **awk** script that will do what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/quux/ && p { p=/qux/; next }
{ p=/qux/ }
{ print }
```

with input:

```
$ cat input.txt
foo bar baz qux
foo bar baz quux qux
foo bar baz quux
foo bar quux
```

gives:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
foo bar baz qux
foo bar quux
```

The **follow-up question** was to delete a line whenever it contains 'quux' and the preceding line did **not** contain 'qux'. A simple negation of p is all there is to do.

```
 cat tst2.awk
 /quux/ && !p { p=/qux/; next }
 { p=/qux/ }
 { print }
```

with input:

```
$ cat del.txt
foo bar baz qux
foo bar baz quux qux
foo bar baz quux
foo bar quux       # to be deleted
```

gives:

```
 awk -f tst2.awk del.txt
 foo bar baz qux
 foo bar baz quux qux
 foo bar baz quux
```

Comment: @MarcLambrichs I just edited my question to make it more specific. How could your code be modified to allow the inverse of condition (b)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` in the following manner:

```
awk '$4 ~/qux/ || $4 !~/quux/' file

foo bar baz
foo bar baz qux
foo bar quux
```